# f(x) = sum of all f(divisors of x except 1 and itself)

Tags: functions, integers, prime-factorization

Given a function $f(x)$
If $x$ is prime then $f(x) = x$
Else $f(x) =$ sum of all f(divisors of x except 1 and itself)

Example: $f(12) = f(6) + f(4) + f(3) + f(2)$
$= f(3) + f(2) + f(2) + 3 + 2 = 3 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 12$

Given distinct three prime integers a, b, c and a positive integer $n$
What is $p$ in terms of $n$ in:
$f((a*b*c)^n) = p(a + b + c)$

Example: $n = 1, p = 3$
$f(abc) = f(ab) + f(ac) + f(bc) + f(a) + f(b) + f(c)$
$=3(a + b + c)$

Comment: See the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)

Comment: I am familiar with the divisor function but the divisors of the numbers are also subjected to the function.

Comment: The subtraction of $1$ and $n$ makes this a mess.  Without it, your function would be multiplicative.  You could then evaluate it at prime powers and be done.